# How to show image in iOS Push Notification Banner using FireBase SDK

Tags: ios, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

In iOS using firebase push notification i cannot see the image on push notification

this is the format i am using to send notification. I can see the notification but not the image

```
{
  "content_available": true,
  "data": {
    "actionId": "219CE497-1FAC-4974-B605-F28B87E756AB",
    "actionName": "display",
    "actionType": "Movie",
    "attachment-url": "http://singteltv.com.sg/_channels/pic_ch1.jpg",
    "dataId": "123fcm-20180327",
    "dataMessage": "test Swathi: !#@$%^&*' 中文 - ไทย 1234567890 1234567891  1234567892  1234567893  1234567894  1234567895",
    "dataTitle": "test Title",
    "media_type": "image"
  },
  "mutable_content": true,
  "notification": {
    "body": "test Swathi: !#@$%^&*' 中文 - ไทย 1234567890 1234567891  1234567892  1234567893  1234567894  1234567895",
    "sound": "default",
    "title": "test Title"
  },
  "to": "cbBGCiyqpVw:APA91bHhAn0xXW8GiixQFmE5pcSpOPYjRRSABrDqR9AWhpMOHqGbRqd25Jrd3rLIOakXuIzGS81vG_QBotlC3fidjkYZmfBsu3iDxJJVYG3uB8bPi1zxXluIpZzU8yWHdnk2vWu00AVn"
}
```

Comment: Let me know if you want additional informations.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a Notification Service Extension in order to download the image before display it.

It's like a service running in background that will allow you to modify the content of the notification before display it to the user.

You can also create a Notification Content Extension that can allow you to display Rich Notification by 3D touching the notification.

Anyway you are almost there, check this great article, it will help you.

[Service Extension](https://makeapppie.com/2017/01/24/using-user-notifications-service-extensions-in/)

[Attachment Notification](https://medium.com/@prianka.kariat/ios-10-notifications-with-attachments-and-much-more-169a7405ddaf)

You can also use Postman to make real-case request, it is a great tool for testing.

I hope it will help you, feel free to ask more information if you are still stuck.